# Ignore the WHERE statement based on conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Let's say that I have a table with some columns and one column is named `col`. I want to apply the following filter in a `SELECT` statement if possible.

- if `col = ""` THEN return the whole table
- otherwise return only the rows where `col = the given value`

Example:

```
col output

10     9
 9     8
 0    10
```

If I want to filter the results based on column `col` then 
I could do a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col = 10
```

and I would get only the rows where col=10.

But I would like to get the full table if the condition was `col = "`.

**EDIT**: Unfortunately, I cannot use the `SET` keyword to set variables.

Comment: `col = ""`? Did you mean if the given value = `""`?

Comment: @SalmanA That's right, yes!

Comment: Is `col` in a different table from the one you want to return? Does this have to be a single query? Could you use a simple `if` condition instead?

Comment: Could you show us an example schema, data, and your expected result please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the "given value" is contained inside a user variable or parameter:

```
WHERE @var = '' OR col = @var
WHERE :var = '' OR col = :var
WHERE ? = '' OR col = ?
```

If you are "building" the query somehow you could simply skip the where clause based on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there something more generic without using the `SET` command?

Comment: You forgot to mention where the given value (10 in your question) is coming from!

Comment: A user defines the given value, e.g. through some UI (API).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the 'given value' coming from if you can't put it in a variable?

Is it kept on another, single row, table? If it is, you could do this with a join:

```
select m.* from maintable m
join giventable g on 1=1
where g.givenvalue=''
or m.col=g.givenvalue
```

Or is it passed as a parameter to a stored procedure or function? If so, you can use almost exactly the syntax in the first answer:

```
select * from maintable m
where param1=''
or m.col=param1
```